# No response from php after calling ajax

Tags: php, jquery

I am calling a PHP file from ajax but not getting any response from the PHP, I inspected there it showing No response available.

```js
var str = "Hi";
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "get_details.php",
  data: str,
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(response) {
    alert(response);
  }
});
```

and my PHP file contains following.

```
<?php

    echo "Hello";

?>
```

Comment: Anyone know about this?

Comment: Have you tried to implement an [error](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax) to see if the AJAX call fails in some way? Alternatively you could look in the developer tools of your browser.

Comment: not able to put a breakpoint after $.ajax({

Comment: anyone know????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return JSON from get_details.php file, or change **dataType** attribute to **html**

Comment: Then add .fail() promise callback and check what error you get

Comment: Thank you for helping, The Problem was I am calling a different file and File was empty.